# how change background color of combobox runtime in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, combobox

please help

i want to change background color of combobox runtime in silverlight i have written following code but its not working

cmbSource.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(51, 51, 51, 51));

where cmbSource is my combobox .

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but you need to edit the template of the combobox, which is pretty annoying actually.  But it is needed since you will need to set the color a lot of places since there is some VisualState s associated to the combobox object.

So you need to open your UserControl in Blend, right click your control, Edit Template, Edit a Copy.  Then make your changes to the template.